# Ubuntu 18 not launching in WSL2

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04, wsl2

I am just starting with WSL2, installed everything as per: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Ran the Ubuntu 18.04 in my windows, everything looked good.

I tried to access the rootfs from LocalState, but found an ext4 VHD instead. I double clicked on it, and my Ubuntu, stopped working. Got an error like "*This file is currently being used*".

Figured it could be because VHD was mounted or something, restarted the system. Now I get the following error instead:
*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.*

I have made the Hypervisor launch as automatic using: *bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto*

I dont know why I am getting the error. Any workarounds ? Or should I reinstall Ubuntu or something ?

Comment: Try to reinstall. If it doesn't help, better add some screenshots of the problem. Why don't you install Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @harrymc suggested in the comment I reset the Distro installation according to the instructions given here: https://winaero.com/reset-unregister-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/

I had to go into *Apps & Features* find my installation (Ubuntu); click on it to reveal *Advanced Options*; And then click on *Reset* tab.

This has worked and I can use the installation again.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.